# Memory increases with each request due to AutoMapper.Map in c# component

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, automapper

We are using **AutoMapper 4.2.1.0** in our Dot net application. We are having lots of classes which neeed to map. For performance problem we have got solution from creator itself. due to this initial loading time & memory also decreases.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37398552/6343798

But we still facing incresed memory issue after each request.
Now our concern is Suppose at start component size is 70 MB then after each request the Size increses by 1 MB, eventually lot of request creates lot of memory use.

We call **Mapper.Map** with each request so may be it is taking to much memory. this is what Dump file memory usages shows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We did a lot of work on the memory for 5.0, have you tried the 5.0 beta?

Comment: Okay, As it was beta version so I have not tried it. But now I will try.

Comment: @Jimmy Bogard
When I updated with 5, I got error. Nullreference and same item key exception.
Previously I was using http://stackoverflow.com/a/6474397 IgnoreAllNonExisting.
So in 5 version, what changes need to be done accordingly?
cfg.CreateMap(newType, oldType).IgnoreAllNonExisting(newType, oldType);